# Dynamic sidebar inside if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { echo ''; } else {

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show an dynamic sidebar inside my div when an guest is visiting the website. Any idea?

```
    <?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo '';
} else {
    echo '<div class="slideraanmeldbuiten">
<div class="slideraanmeldbinnen">
<div class="slideraanmeld">
<div class="slideraanmeldinside">

<?php 
 // Custom widget Area Start
 if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Zoektermen 1') ) : ?>
<?php endif;
// Custom widget Area End
?>

</div>
</div></div></div>';
};
?>
```

Comment: Why not just do `if(!is_user_logged_in()){echo "sidebarstuffgoeshere";}`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo '';
} else {
    echo '<div class="slideraanmeldbuiten">
<div class="slideraanmeldbinnen">
<div class="slideraanmeld">
<div class="slideraanmeldinside">

<?php 
 // Custom widget Area Start
 if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Zoektermen 1') ) : ?>
<?php endif;
// Custom widget Area End
?>
<?php
'</div>
</div></div></div>';
};
?>
```

control your php tags you do close it and not open the last tag. and you also forgot the ' befor the  tag

Answer (score 0):

Done it myself this way:

```
<?php if( is_home() || is_front_page() ) : ?>
    <?php if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
<div class="slideraanmeldbuiten">
<div class="slideraanmeldbinnen">
<div class="slideraanmeld">
<div class="slideraanmeldinside">

<?php if( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Aanmeldvak') ) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>


</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```